# Doctrine undefined method bindvalue

Tags: php, doctrine

I'm extremely new to Doctrine and working on a project and I have a problem when I call this function :

```
   public function authentification($login,$passe) {
    $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->select('count(user.id)')
            ->from("user")
            ->where("login = ?" . $login . "'")
            ->andWhere("passe = ?" . $passe . "'")
            ->bindValue(1, $login)
            ->bindValue(2, $passe); 
    return $q->count();             
}
```

I get this error:

> Call to undefined method Doctrine_Query::bindValue()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a `bindValue` method in [`Doctrine_Query`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/ormold/1.2/class-Doctrine_Query.html). Use it like this:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->select('count(user.id)')
        ->from("user")
        ->where("login = ?", $login)
        ->andWhere("passe = ?", passe);
```

You can find the documentation [here](http://doctrine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/en/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#where-clause).